# Converting infinite series to definite integral

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Is there a method to transform the following infinite series to a definite integral? The problem is from my 1989 textbook on Calculus by Thomas and Finney, Ch 7., which focuses on methods of integration.  I'm just trying to refresh my calculus, but I don't know much about series.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^{n + 1} \frac{n}{n^{2} + (n + k)^{2}}$$

Comment: $lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n}{n^2+(n+k)^2}=lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n/n^2}{n^2/n^2+(n+k)^2/n^2}=lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1/n}{1+1+k^2/n^2+2k/n}=lim_{n\to\infty}1/n\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2+k^2/n^2+2k/n}=\int_0^1\frac{1}{2+x^2+2x}dx$ Typing in Math content is really easy. You don't have to draw and paste your question.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm going to try to find a tutorial on how to enter math equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint : Divide numerator and denominator by $n^2$.

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n}{n^2+(n+k)^2} &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n/n^2}{n^2/n^2+(n+k)^2/n^2} \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1/n}{1+1+k^2/n^2+2k/n} \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2+k^2/n^2+2k/n} \\
&=\int_0^1\frac{1}{2+x^2+2x}dx \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: How does it work?